# Is there a way to set default parameters for multiple function without have to copy paste it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple function with the same default parameters for all of it.

Is there somehow to add default parameters for all of it without copying and paste?

```
// 1st function
export function modify(id, values, failCB = (err) => error(" Error"), successCB = () => success("✌ Success")) {
    //...
    if (err) {
        failCB(err.message);
    } else {
        successCB()
    }
}

// 2nd function
export function remove(id, failCB = (err) => error(" Error"), successCB = () => success("✌ Success")) {
    //...
    if (err) {
        failCB(err.message);
    } else {
        successCB()
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare variables that store the default value of the parameters and refer those variables instead:

```js
const defaultCbIfFailed = err => error(" Error");
const defaultCbIfSuccess = () => success("✌ Success");

//1st function
export function modify(id, values, failCB = defaultCbIfFailed, successCB = defaultCbIfSuccess) {
    //...
    if (err) {
        failCB(err.message);
    } else {
        successCB()
    }
}

// 2nd function
export function remove(id, failCB = defaultCbIfFailed, successCB = defaultCbIfSuccess) {
    //...
    if (err) {
        failCB(err.message);
    } else {
        successCB()
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use function declarations for your callbacks and pass references to those:

```js
// 1st function
export function modify(id, values, failCB, successCB) {
    //...
    if (err) {
        failCB(err.message);
    } else {
        successCB()
    }
}

// 2nd function
export function remove(id, values, failCB, successCB) {
    //...
    if (err) {
        failCB(err.message);
    } else {
        successCB()
    }
};

function failCB = (err) => error(" Error")
function successCB = () => success("✌ Success")
```

Answer (score 0):

I knew what Shrihan answered. What I actually want is something like this

```
removeSubject.parameters = failCB;
```